# Cython prange with function reading from numpy array (memoryview) freezes, why?

Tags: multithreading, numpy, thread-safety, openmp, cython

I have to use the rows of a numpy array sequentially so I am doing that with a loop. I tried adding prange for speed but it ends up freezing. I am most likely doing something wrong, I may be misunderstanding the meaning of a race condition in this context. What can be done to fix the problem or to treat the array rows in parallel fashion correctly? Reproducible code below for IPython cells:

```
%load_ext cython
import numpy as np
```

```
%%cython --compile-args=-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp --force
# if on Windows, replace line above with: %%cython --compile-args=/openmp --link-args=/openmp --force

cimport cython
from cython.parallel cimport prange

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef double sum_row(double [:] arr) nogil:
    cdef int i
    cdef int size = arr.shape[0]
    cdef double s = 0

    for i in range(size):
        s += arr[i]

    return s

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef double sum_all_rows(double [:,:] arr) nogil:
    cdef int i
    cdef int n_rows = arr.shape[1] + 1
    cdef double s = 0

    for i in range(n_rows):
        s += sum_row(arr[i])

    return s

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef double sum_all_rows_parallel(double [:,:] arr) nogil:
    cdef int i
    cdef int n_rows = arr.shape[1] + 1
    cdef double s = 0

    for i in prange(n_rows):
        s += sum_row(arr[i])

    return s
```

```
X = np.array([[3.14, 2.71, 0.002],
              [0.5, 1, 4.21],
              [0.001, 0.002, 0.003],
              [-0.1, -0.11, -0.12]])
```

```
%timeit sum_all_rows(X)
```

*754 ns ± 38.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)*

```
sum_all_rows_parallel(X)
```

And it hangs... I stopped it after roughly 5 minutes. I did not observe any increasing memory usage nor CPU usage.

I have used the toy examples of prange before seeing the expected speedups, so I am able to compile properly.

Also, any suggested readings to better understand this kind of issue?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `nogil` means two slightly different things in different contexts. In

```
cpdef double sum_all_rows_parallel(double [:,:] arr) nogil:
```

it means "this function does not require the GIL and can be called without it", while in:

```
with nogil:
# or
prange(..., nogil=True)
```

it means "release the GIL".

Therefore the GIL is never actually released in your example (since `sum_all_rows_parallel` is presumably called from Python, which holds the GIL), but `prange` is working under the assumption that it has been released.

What you should do is change `prange(...)` to `prange(...,nogil=True)`. You possibly also need to remove the `nogil` from the `sum_all_rows_parallel` function definition.

---

Arguably it's a bug in Cython that it doesn't warn you about the issue, and should be reported. However, I suspect it may not be easily fixed.

Comment: Thank you! That was it, it is indeed frustrating that there is no warning or error message. I implemented the changes and now it runs. It is much slower but I suspect that it is due to the overhead introduced by the threading given the array is very small.